DTM and DSM from the same LAZ file - extent do not match
I'm trying to extract tree tops, and I have successfully processed dozens of LAZ files with R, but I have a problem with one.
als_dir <- "C:/Users/bzzzzzzi/Documents/dummy/KRON86/09/"
als <- lidR::catalog(folder = als_dir)
st_crs(als) <- st_crs(2180)
opt_filter(als) <- "-keep_class 2 3 4 5 6"
DSM  <- lidR::rasterize_canopy(las = als,res = 0.5,algorithm = dsmtin())
DTM <- lidR::rasterize_terrain(las = als,res = 0.5,algorithm = tin())
nDSM <- DSM - DTM

And at this point, I'm getting an error
[-] extents do not match

I already had this error in one case, but removing class filtering helped.
Unfortunately not in this case.
I exported DTM and DSM to tiff files and compared them in QGIS
It turns out that both files have different sizes

DSM is 2098 x 2359 with extent 404613.5 - 405662.5 | 674572.5 - 675752.0


DTM is 2097 x 2359 with extent 404614.0 - 405662.5 | 674572.5 - 675752.0

I was trying to fix this by changing the algorithms (p2r, pitfree, knnidw), then I was trying with adding "shape" parameter - without success.
Unfortunately, this is where my knowledge and skills end. I kindly ask for help.
Problematic LAZ file is from Polish national geoportal
https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/NumDaneWys/DanePomiaroweLAZ/4735/4735_335921_N-33-84-A-a-3-4-2.laz

Use the DSM as a template for the DTM
DSM  <- lidR::rasterize_canopy(las = als,res = 0.5,algorithm = dsmtin())
DTM <- lidR::rasterize_terrain(las = als,res = DSM,algorithm = tin())

